# Observe stdout from multiplatform kotlin commonTest code

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, kotlin, stdout, kotlin-multiplatform

I just want to see the output from a few simple `println(...)` in my Kotlin mulitplatform `commonTest` code. My `build.gradle.kts` looks a little like:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.3.61"
}


kotlin {

   sourceSets {

        val commonMain by getting { ... }

        val commonTest by getting {
           dependencies {
              implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common")
              implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common")
           }
        }

        val jvmMain by getting { ... }

        val jvmTest by getting {
           dependencies {
              implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
           }
        }

        // and so on ...

   }

}
```

Meanwhile in `~/src/commonTest/kotlin/my/company/library/CommonTest.kt`:

```
package my.company.library

import kotlin.test.*

class CommonTest() {

   @Test
   fun testTrue() {
      println("Hello, test!")
      assertTrue(true)
   }

}
```

For the time being I'm running tests like this

`./gradlew jvmTest`

I want to see `Hello, test!` show up in the terminal. I don't mind typing a little extra on the command line.

Various answers around SO involving `testLogging.showStandardStreams` refer to the "standard" gradle test target, and I'm not sure how or if it actually interacts with the multiplatform test targets.

Comment: I've got the same issue but with Kotlin/Native, I've managed to see the result by opening the "output.bin" file located at "build/test-results/nativeTest/binary", but it might not be present in JVM tests. It's not the ideal solution, but at least I could see it. Hope you can too!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work by adding this to your `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your gradle config:

```
iosTest {
    testLogging {
        events("PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED")
        exceptionFormat = "full"
        showStandardStreams = true
        showStackTraces = true
    }
}
```

for JVM it would be similar but then under the block `jvmTest`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this worked:

```kotlin
afterEvaluate {
    tasks.withType<AbstractTestTask> {
        testLogging {
            showStandardStreams = true
        }
    }
}
```